# how to install meteor on Ubuntu?

Tags: javascript, php, ubuntu, curl

I want to run meteor application in ubuntu. I run following command to install curl.
sudo apt-get install curl

But it gives me following errors:

$sudo apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package curl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'curl' has no installation candidate

please help me to install curl and meteor.

Comment: Quite what this question has to do with `php` I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

And you might want to consider using this command:

```
 sudo apt-get install libcurl3 php5-curl
```

Then, to make it easier just use the command `wget -qO- https://install.meteor.com | sh`. Curl was used on earlier versions of ubuntu. It is not really an essential tool, but some tutorials use it indeed.